# semantic/gulp npm install mess

Tags: meteor, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I'm trying out semantic-ui in a meteor/npm environment and am left a little dissatisfied with the install process. I love the interactivity, but it's made a mess of my project. I now have semantic folders inside my `node_modules` directory and outside, a `semantic.json` config file in the root, and my `node_modules` directory is now just completely full of ugly `gulp` folders (`node_modules` was empty before the install). Is this how it is supposed to go? If so, I'm out, I want to keep it clean, simple, and contained.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this issue. I ended up doing the following:

```
npm uninstall gulp semantic-ui
```

And add semantic like this:

1. create an empty `custom.semantic.json` file within your client library folder. suggested location of `/client/lib/semantic-ui/custom.semantic.json` depending on your applications structure
2. Run in termnial    `meteor add semantic:ui flemay:less-autoprefixer jquery`

That way you have 1 folder of semantic inside your lib.

Comment: I saw this and hesitated since everything is moving towards npm. But, it looks like the better of the options. Thanks!